# Docker node.js out of source require

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to require `pg` in a module outside of the site folder but I get the following error:

```
> node app.js
/deploy/ui/site
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
Require stack:
- /deploy/lib/db.js
- /deploy/ui/site/app.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/deploy/lib/db.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/deploy/lib/db.js', '/deploy/ui/site/app.js' ]
}
```

I have the following files and folders

/lib/db.js

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
```

/ui/site/app.js

```
const db = require('../../lib/db')
```

I'm running it successfully locally in VS Code but when running the same in Docker I get the error. I have also tried to install pg globally using

```
npm install -g pg
```

Verifying that it is installed with

```
/ # npm ls -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
+-- corepack@0.17.0
+-- npm@9.5.1
`-- pg@8.10.0
```

Unfortunately same problem.

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set env params
ENV RENDERTYPE=il2
ENV GAMEPATH="G:\\Spel\\"

COPY lib /deploy/lib
COPY mission /deploy/mission

# node_modules excluded in .dockerignore
COPY ui/site /deploy/ui/site

# COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g pg@8.8.0

# Create and set the working directory
WORKDIR /deploy/ui/site

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
# COPY ui/site/package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --omit=dev --loglevel verbose

# Expose port 3000 for the application
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the application
# CMD ["node", "app.js"]
CMD ["npm", "start"] # run a temporary http server for testing
```

Comment: When you run the container, do you map any volumes into it? Particularly onto any path containing the module? If you do, then that mapping 'hides' anything in the image in that path.

Comment: @HansKilianno, none. I COPY all to the image

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what the problem was. It seems like I at some point started with the re-usable code laying the basis for the site I also set up `package.json` for that. I updated the `Dockerfile` with the below to install the dependencies

```
# Removed
# RUN npm install -g pg@8.8.0 

# Added
WORKDIR /deploy
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
```